# Why do I get an error when I want to print the results of the query? Python 2.7 Psycopg2 Windows 10

Tags: postgresql, python-2.7, windows-10, anaconda, psycopg2

I am trying to make a basic print of the results of a query using Python and psycopg2. here is my code:

```
import psycopg2
try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect (database = "datawh", user="myuser", password="111111", host="aaaaa.aaaaaa.com", port="1111")
    conn.set_client_encoding('Latin1')
except:
    print "Unable to connect to the database"

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM inspections where county_name = 'Abey'")

rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print row
```

I know the connection to the database is working because I get some results and the try-catch statement doesn't show anything, however, in some point the execution throws an error:

```
('D1', '23', 'Abey', '2010', '2334544'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Daniela/Documents/inspections_rank.py", line 21, in <module>
    print row
IOError: [Errno 0] Error
```

I've also tried replacing using:

```
for record in cursor:
    print record
```

Instead of `rows = cursor.fetchall()`, but it doesn't work either. No matter how many times and which options I've tried, doesn't seem to work and I am desperate now. Do you have any idea why? I am using Windows 10 and visual studio code. I am new with postgreSQL and psycog2, so any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This seems to be some sort of windows issue writing to stdout.
There are some similar issue that come up on a quick Google search: 
https://github.com/tartley/colorama/issues/101
https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/5019
Looks like it may be UTF-8 issue.

Comment: You're probably right @MichaelRobellard, as I got less errors when I changed to UTF-8. However, as the problem persisted, I decided to give up printing the results (that was not the final purpose at all) and instead, update the data I needed directly into the table. The update query performed without any issue. Thanks anyway!